# A variation of the Coupon collector's problem

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector

I wonder how I can address the following scenario:

I am sampling from a given discrete distribution with $n$ categories/coupons (not necessarily uniform). Let $U_k$ represents the number of unique values seen after $k$ samples. I would like to estimate the confidence interval of $U_k$.

The closest paper I could find was:

Shank, N.B. and Yang, H., 2013. Coupon collector problem for non-uniform coupons and random quotas. the electronic journal of combinatorics, 20(2), p.P33.

But it finds the expected k for having at least one of each type of coupon been selected.

Comment: The *expected k for having at least one of each type of coupon been selected* should be the answer to the following summation,
$$\sum_{k} kP(U_k = n)$$
I haven't looked at the paper. But if you can get their result to resemble the above form, you could get the expression for $P(U_k)$, which may help you estimate the confidence interval.

Comment: The full probability distribution for $U_k$ is as follows:
$$
P(U_k=i)={\binom ni{k\brace i}i!\over n^k}.
$$
Here, ${k \brace i}$ is a Stirling number of the second kind, given by
$$
{k\brace i}=\frac1{i!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom ij(i-j)^k.
$$